# liquibase dropFirst ignores schema

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

How can I ask liquibase to drop schema when dropFirst is enabled? I'm using Postgres 9x and schema is created upon all DDL/DSL is executed:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset some-author:create-schema-foo

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS FOO;
```

I'm in spring-boot app and here is how dropFirst is enabled:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    drop-first: true
```

Whenever I start migration I can see something happening but then there is error like "table already exists". But this table should be already removed when dropFirst is active, so I suppose I need to delete schema

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: "*Postgres 9.x*" covers 7 major versions, 5 of them being no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a problem with missing default-schema:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    drop-first: true
    default-schema: FOO
```

After this change it works as expected